# NServicesBus disable FLR for specific exceptions completely

Tags: nservicebus

I'm trying to disable retries for some specific exceptions completely.

I know that in my code - when I'm trying to handle message X and if the handler throw a "ZZZ" type exception, I'm sure there's no way any number of retries would help;

What I want to do is send that message directly to error queue immediately without any retries.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but since you are trying to circumvent the plumbing builtin for a very specific scenario, you could handle the message in a try/catch and either send the message directly to the error queue or let the FLR/SLR handle it.

**Please note,** this is **not** an ideal scenario. In most cases, it is actively discouraged to handle the error handling of messages and instead allow the infrastructure to manage it.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
    public void Handle(SomeCommand message)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do thing that might throw exception
        }
        catch (SpecificException ex)
        {
            _bus.Send(new Address("errorQueue", "machine"), message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** I'm promoting Marcin's comment to be included in this answer so it isn't missed:

> Please bear in mind that by using this approach without setting
>   appropriate message headers you will lose the ability to return these
>   failed messages to the source queue. Please take a look at this doco
>   for details: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers#retries-handling-headers. – Marcin
>   Hoppe

Comment: Please bear in mind that by using this approach without setting appropriate message headers you will lose the ability to return these failed messages to the source queue. Please take a look at this doco for details: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers#retries-handling-headers.

Comment: what does that note about headers mean ? is there something to be added to the code sample above ?

Comment: Without those headers, ServiceControl won't know which queue the message needs to go to in order to replay it. However, if you don't use Service Pulse and you manually move messages to replay them, you won't see any difference. With that said, I highly recommend setting those headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't for the first level retries, only for the [second level retries](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries#second-level-retries-custom-retry-policy). I personally wouldn't worry about it (I have something similar, where certain exceptions I know that it won't be fixed). There's generally no downside to letting them go in the FLR.

Comment: Thank you. The downside in my case - was performance.. as it creates a lot of extra messages and slow's the whole processing down

Comment: You could try to circumvent this (not tested) by setting a header the first time you process it and checking for this in your handler? Effectively this would mean you could prevent the FLR, if this works. Helpful link: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/header-manipulation#writing-outgoing-headers-from-a-handler